# OCMStub sends OCMConstraint instance to to real method upon stub creation

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm trying to test the URL/path against a request is (or would be) made from a REST-client class using OCMock. The client uses RestKit (which uses AFNetworking) for the communication.
Therefore my plan was to:

1. Create a block which checks if a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` URL is the desired one.
2. Create a partial mock of the of `AFHTTPClient`.
3. Mock (stub) the `enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:` method with the block (of 1.).
4. Create a mock of `RKObjectManager` and set its `HTTPClient` property to the
   `AFHTTPClient` partial-mock (of 2.).
5. Init an instance of my client-class with the mock-manager (from 4.).
6. Invoke the method of this instance of which the URL is to be checked.
7. Verify that `enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:` was invoked.

I'm not sure if I'm getting OCMock wrong because I couldn't find examples on mocking methods that take one or more arguments like I need to. ...never the less, this is how I tried to achieve the goal:

```
    void (^checkBlock)(NSInvocation *) = ^(NSInvocation *invocation) {

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = nil;
        [invocation getArgument:&requestOperation atIndex:0];

        XCTAssert(requestOperation != nil);

        NSString *path = requestOperation.request.URL.path;
        XCTAssert([path containsString:@"/rest/user/authenticate"]);
    };

    AFHTTPClient *httpClientMock = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FAServerUrl]];
    OCMPartialMock(httpClientMock);

    [OCMStub([httpClientMock enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:[OCMArg isNotNil]]) andDo:checkBlock];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = OCMClassMock([RKObjectManager class]);

    [OCMStub([objectManager HTTPClient]) andReturn:httpClientMock];

    FAUserClient *userClient = [[FAUserClient alloc] initWithUser:nil objectManager:objectManager];

    [userClient getAccessTokenForUsername:@"testuser"
                                 password:@"pass123"
                                  success:^(NSString *token, NSArray *roles) {
                                  }
                                  failure:^(NSInteger errorCode, NSError *error) {                                          
                                  }];

    OCMVerify([httpClientMock enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:OCMOCK_ANY]);
```

But on `[OCMStub([httpClientMock enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:[OCMArg isNotNil]]) andDo:checkBlock];` I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1).
Apparently creating the mock-stub (with `OCMStub`) invokes the to be stubbed method, with the given `[OCMArg isNotNil]`. I thought A: the parameter just has a declarative meaning and B: this creates a stub and does not invoke the method right away.

Any help or suggestions leading into the "right" direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

As well tried:

```
    OCMStub([httpClientMock enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj) {
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *request = (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)obj;
        NSString *path = request.request.URL.path;
        XCTAssert([path containsString:@"/rest/user/authenticate"]);
        return YES;
    }]]);
```

...with the same "result".

Best,
gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Looked more closely. You are calling `OCMPartialMock(httpClientMock)`. This does not convert the object you call it on, it *returns* a partial mock. Capture the result in a variable.

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClientMock = OCPartialMock([[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FAServerUrl]]);
```

You should still make the change noted below in your `andDo:` block. You can also use the "modern" syntax for this:

```
OCMStub([myObject myMethod]).andDo(myBlock);
```

**Original**

I think the issue might be the code in the `andDo:` block.

```
[invocation getArgument:&requestOperation atIndex:0];
```

For all Objective-C methods, NSInvocation has two default arguments, `self` and `_cmd` at indexes 0 and 1. Try getting the argument at index 2.

You might also consider including NSInvocation+OCMAdditions which gives you `getArgumentAtIndexAsObject` . Another alternative is using `[OCMArg checkWithBlock:]` in which the arg is handed to your evaluation block directly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately the problem persists. `OCMStub()` invokes the method (it should stub) directly, passing the `OCMConstraint` as parameter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't notice that `CCMParticialMock()` returns the mock without changing the given instance. Thanks!!